# DOCKER: Mysql dockerfile remains in exited state after "docker run"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have to start a mysql container through a dockerfile, in which I simply have to set the environment variables, I wrote the dockerfile like this, but when I do the "docker run" it remains in exited state.

```
FROM mysql

ENV DB_HOST=localhost
ENV DB_NAME=productsdb
ENV DB_USER=root
ENV DB_PWD=mm22
ENV DB_DIALECT=mysql
ENV SERVER_PORT=5000
ENV DB_PORT=3306
```

Comment: Do this using docker-compose, show some logs and the command you used to run the container.

Comment: use "docker logs -f <container_id>" and give more information about the logs.

Comment: Remember that these variables are extremely easy to extract from the image – `docker inspect` will list them out in a single JSON object – and it might be better to run the unmodified `mysql` image but pass the variables at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no error in your container add option -d to run container background.

`docker run -d yourMysqlImage:yourTag`

If you didn't build image yet.

`docker build -f yourDockerfile`

And you should check container logs to see what happend.

1. List all container:

- `docker ps -a`

2. Check logs:

- `docker logs yourContainerId`

Here is my quick start command:

`docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql:latest`

Answer (score 0):

When you run the container, it outputs - in the log - the following message

```
You need to specify one of the following as an environment variable:
- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
- MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
- MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

Basically, MySQL won't start without a root password or being told that no password is OK.

Add

```
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=myrootpassword
```

to your Dockerfile and it'll run.